# How to access element from component interaction?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to change the `background` with a condition in `component interaction`.

I need to compare the target element with the current element.

for example:

```
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == this ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target"  >any text ...</span>
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == this ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target" >any text ...</span>
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == this ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target" >any text ...</span>
enter code here
```

How to access elements(this) from `component interaction`?

Comment: Can you please provide additional context? The condition needs to evaluate to a boolean, but there is no concept of an html element explicitly within typescript, and manipulating/referring to DOM directly is generally a mistake.

Comment: @theMayer for example in output i can access to element with `$event.target`, can i have a solution in same output in `component interaction`

Comment: what does `a condition in component interaction` mean? specifically `component interaction`?

Comment: If you're using `ngFor`, you can assign a variable from the loop instead of `this` in your template, then set that variable as appropriate when you have your click handler. Otherwise, you can define an enum which you can use. More code would be helpful (e.g. what are you clicking).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is assign a value from the template that can then be used to compare against. The `(click)` event and the style evaluation happen at completely different times in the change detection lifecycle, so that's part of what is going on.

**Template**

```
<span *ngFor="let item of spans"
     [style.background]="targetElem === item ? 'red' : '#eee'"
     (click)="targetElem = item">item.text</span>
```

**Code**

```
spans = [ 
  { text: 'Text 1' },
  { text: 'Text 2' },
  { text: 'Text 3' }
];

targetElem;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `#` syntax for declares dom elements as variables:

```
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == s1  ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target"  #s1>any text ...</span>
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == s2  ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target" #s2>any text ...</span>
<span 
     [style.background]="targetElem == s3  ? 'red' : '#eee'" 
    (click)="targetElem = $event.target" #s3>any text ...</span>
```

tested in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbtjlc)